# Selenium and LINK_TEXT

Tags: selenium, linktext, partiallinktext

I tried to scrapp a cost with a LINK TEXT but my scrapping method can't find the TEXT:

```
budget = budgets.append((driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Total budget/expenditure:')).text)
```

The web site is : https://keep.eu/projects/12880/A-la-d-couverte-des-plus-be-EN/

It works with the XPATH but i need to scrap many page like this one and sometimes the To total budget/expenditure and European Union Funding was not exactly at the same place.

The error is that :

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Total budget/expenditure:"}
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
```

I don't know why sometimes I can used the LINK-TEXT and sometimes no.
I tried PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT too but it can't works.

Comment: How about using the css-selector?

Comment: Yes but i have to many <p>.

Comment: `p:nth-child(11) > strong` try this

Comment: Thanks that's ok for this one but i have the same probleme than for the XPATH. For the the other webpage i haven't exactly the same css selector. I need to find why the LINK TEXT can't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Link Text

A linkText is used to identify the hyperlinks on a web page.  It can be determined with the help of an anchor tag `<a>`.

But your desired element is within a `<strong>` tag, so ***By.LINK_TEXT*** won't work here.

```
<p>
    <strong>Total budget/expenditure: </strong>
    " EUR 313 300.00"
</p>
```

---

### Solution

To locate the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p//strong[contains(., 'Total budget/expenditure:')]")
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p//strong[starts-with(., 'Total budget/expenditure:')]")
  ```

Comment: Thanks thats works with "//p[starts-with(., 'Total budget/expenditure:')]"

Comment: @rocheteau Finetuned the answer as per your observations.

Comment: With //strong or with //p//strong I found that: 'Total budget/expenditure:'. If I want to found the number only //p works.